# sendTransaction and events not working in NodeJS app

Tags: go-ethereum, events, nodejs

I have a contract deployed on the testnet, I can do the following within geth:
`reference.transfer.sendTransaction(bob, 467, {from:me})`

However I can't do this within my node console (with web3 etc. all loaded), as I receive the following error:

> ```
> reference.transfer.sendTransaction(bob, 246, {from: me, gas:200000}) 
> Error: Transaction not confirmed
> at Object.module.exports.InvalidResponse (/Users/jbowkett/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
> at RequestManager.send (/Users/jbowkett/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61:22)
> at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (/Users/jbowkett/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:58)
> at SolidityFunction.sendTransaction (/Users/jbowkett/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:133:26)
> at repl:1:20
> at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
> at bound (domain.js:287:14)
> at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
> at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
> at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
> at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
> ```

Also, my events on transfer fire in geth, but I can't see if they will fire within my node app, because of the above error.

I need the node app to receive events because I want to make external calls to other node apis.

Comment: Which version of geth were you using?

Comment: Is this issue to do with the unlocking of your account necessary to spend some gas for the transaction?

Comment: Hi @James B. Did you ever get this resolved? Can you provide answers to the user's questions above so that we can get this answered for you. Thanks.